# Managing project references in an application which uses a DI container

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I recently have read about the domain driven design. Finally, I came across the structure that my project should have. The structure would be like :

1. **MyApp.Domain** which contains entities and repositories interfaces.
2. **MyApp.Domain.Services** contains services.
3. **MyApp.Infrastructure**
4. **MyApp.Persistence** Contains the repositories implementation
5. **MyApp.Application** contains viewmodels and services
6. **MyApp.Site**

Right now, I just need to reference the **MyApp.Domain** and **MyApp.Application** to my site. On the other hand, if I want to use Unity as Ioc. The question is, Should I make reference to **MyApp.Domain.Services** and **MyApp.Persistence** as well? in order to register types?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How else would Your "Application" know about Your business objects, 
if You don't tell it, which assembly they're registered in ?

If You're looking for a more 'Plug-in' based approach, then it's a different story..

If speaking about plugins (not sure how Unity does that)
but the only way I got this to work (withing reasonable amount of effort)
was unit [Autofac modules](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2015/06/autofac-modules.html)

You'd still need to have a place where You register your assemblies
and have something like a 'Filesystem watcher' that monitors a pat for new .dll's and loads them ect..

Answer (score 0):

A common architecture when practicing DDD is the [Onion Architecture](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/10/ddd-onion-architecture).  Mostly because it has several improvements over a typical n-tier architecture with barely any downsides.

It allows your domain and domain model to be at the heart of the software.  The domain services layer would usually have a dependency on the persistence layer.  In an Onion Architecture, this is flipped and the persistence layer holds the references to the domain services/model.  To access the persistence layer, the interfaces for the key classes in the persistence layer are held in the domain layer and IoC is used to wire up the instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why have you created six different projects? They are just a fictionary separation. If you are the only developer, do you not trust yourself? If you are more than one developer, are your communication so bad that you can't agree on in which direction dependencies go?

Good separation comes from communication and talk within a team, and not because you have created multiple projects (adding a reference is really easy).

If you want to make sure that the code keeps good quality, introduce code reviews, measure the quality with the built in analytic tools or simply write unit tests.

Therefore, project references are not the problem and never have been. Add the reference in a way that makes it easy to run and maintain the application.

If you are serious about DDD forget about the project structure. It doesn't really matter that much. Understand the methodology and what's important in DDD. Buy the blue book by Eric Evans.